# System throws error in selenium program controlling pop using c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

System throws error:

> the type or namespace name''PopupWindowFinder' could not be found(are
>   you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

In this line:-

```
 PopupWindowFinder finder = new PopupWindowFinder(driver);
```

and another error:-

> 'IWebDriver ' does not contain a definition for 'SwitchToWindow' and
>   no extension method 'SwitchToWindow' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'List' could be found(are you missing a using
>   directive or assembly reference?)"

in this line:-

```
driver.SwitchToWindow(currentHandle);
```

Find the code below:-

```
        PopupWindowFinder finder = new PopupWindowFinder(driver);
        string popupWindowHandle = finder.Click(element);
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(popupWindowHandle);
        driver.Close();
        driver.SwitchToWindow(currentHandle);
```

Comment: actually system throw error message while running it

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the Support UI namespace?

Add this to the top of your file

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
```

Also, I don't think there is a `driver.SwitchToWindow()` method. Did you mean `driver.SwitchTo().Window()`?